# Shopify Create order

Tags: ios, json, api, shopify

I'm trying to create an order from my IOS app to my Shopify site.

This is what the documentation says I should do.

Create a simple order with only a product variant id.
    
    `POST /admin/orders.json
    {
      "order": {
        "line_items": [
          {
            "variant_id": 447654529,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }`

It does not say much more.

Here is what I got.

```
<code>
NSMutableDictionary *lineItem1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[lineItem1 setObject:@"1125533997" forKeyedSubscript:@"variant_id"];
[lineItem1 setObject:@"1" forKeyedSubscript:@"quantity"];

NSMutableArray *lineItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[lineItems addObject:lineItem1];


NSMutableDictionary *orders=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[orders setObject:lineItems forKeyedSubscript:@"line_items"];


NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:orders options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

myString=[JuicyApi md5HexDigest:myString];


//Set parameter
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setObject:myString forKeyedSubscript:@"order"];

//Generate the request with the give settings
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [self getRequestWithFunction:@"admin/orders.json" requestType:@"POST" params:params ssl:true];

</code>
```

The server is giving me a response that says.

```
<code>
{"errors":{"order":"expected String to be a Hash"}}
</code>
```

I tried hashing all of it, only the values, in this example everything in order, can't get it to work. Am I hashing it incorrectly?

What am I missing here?

Comment: I came across this looking for the solution of same. I have fixed it now. It has nothing to do with hashing, that error is misleading. Don't create a hash string from your JSON. Just post JSON and make sure your JSON is valid and doesn't have any extra escaping. That hash string error will go and it will work. From your code I would suggest create a dictionary including "order" in it and then convert it into JSON string only once. If you convert a sub part of dictionary into JSON first then the parent again that will create extra escaping which caused this issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I got fixed by setting the proper header before making the request
setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")